# Why does my csv file read from pandas get unnamed columns?

Tags: python, pandas

```
def filter_csv(intputfile, outputfile):
    df = pd.read_csv(intputfile,delimiter=',')
    df = df.fillna('')
    for index, row in df.iterrows():

        print(index, row)

    df.to_csv(outputfile)
```

When I run it, it reported some columns like below:

```
Unnamed: 27               NaN
Unnamed: 28               NaN
Unnamed: 29               NaN
Unnamed: 30               NaN
Unnamed: 31               NaN
```

However, each column in my csv file has a column name and I dont understand why it reports this. Does this harm?

Answer (score 1):

Are you reloading this a bunch of times? 
`df.to_csv` has `index=True` as a default.  This adds a column to the CSV `Unnammed: X` (unless your index is named), for the index number.

Try by doing : `df.to_csv(outputfile, index=False)`